# Listener Removal

Tags: java, javafx, listener

I have a listener addition like this:

```
lwebview.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener() {
                public void changed(ObservableValue pobservable, Object poldstate, Object pnewstate) {
                    if (pnewstate.toString().equals("SUCCEEDED")) {
                        //code to be executed
                    }
                }
            });
```

Now my question is, is there any way with which this listener can be removed after execution? I am pretty new to these type of things.Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You should separately create the `ChangeListener` and keep a reference of it.

```
ChangeListener<Worker.State> listener = new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> pobservable, Worker.State poldstate, Worker.State pnewstate) {
            if (pnewstate = Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                //code to be executed
            }
        }
    };

lwebview.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(listener);
```

When you need to remove it later:

```
lwebview.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().removeListener(listener);
```

If you just need the listener to stay until it becomes "succeeded", then you can:

```
lwebview.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Worker.State>() {
        public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Worker.State> pobservable, Worker.State poldstate, Worker.State pnewstate) {
            if (pnewstate = Worker.State.SUCCEEDED) {
                //code to be executed
                lwebview.getEngine().getLoadWorker().stateProperty().removeListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
```